# List entities belonging to an association in Doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine, dql

Let's say I have a "Person" entity. A person can belong to a "Group". They are associated through a **ManyToMany, Join Table** strategy.

The general code looks like this:

```php
/**
 * Vendor\AcmeBundle\Entity\Person
 *
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Vendor\AcmeBundle\Entity\PersonRepository")
 */
class Person extends BaseUser
{

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Vendor\AcmeBundle\Entity\Group")
 */
protected $groups;

}
```

and the group entity

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Group extends BaseGroup
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $publicName;
    }
```

**What do I want to achieve?**

Given a group, list users belonging to that group in a consistent way, including pagination options (*aka* limit and offset)

Something like this:

```
function getUserFromGroup(Group $group, $criteria, $limit, $offset){};
```

**Considerations:**

- The entities are mutable, they can be adapted to achieve this requisite (*e.g. the association could be changed from unidirectional to bidirectional*)
- The amount of person entities is in the thousands (2000~8000)
- The amount of groups is less than 10

Answer (score 0):

This is explained in the [Symfony2 Book, chapter on Doctrine](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#fetching-objects-from-the-database)

For your case, I would suggest using the `findBy()` method.

From the [official doctrine documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html):

```php
function getUserFromGroup($group, $criteria, $limit, $offset){
    // You should probably build the criteria into a paramaters array,
    // but I'll just asume it's "fieldName" => "valueToFilterBy"
    $criteria['groups'] = $group;

    $users = $em->getRepository('AppBundle\Entity\User')
        ->findBy(
            $criteria, // Filter by columns
            array('name' => 'ASC'), // Sorting
            $limit, // How many entries to select
            $offset   // Offset
        );

    return $users;
};
```

Comment: Yeah, but you are missing the important part: those 10 users have to belong to the group provided: $group, which is not a string, it's an entity, and it's related to it through a third table (Join table), so I'm guessing it requires some DQL voodoo

Comment: First parameter is filtering by property. So, you're selecting entities of type User, and filtering them by their group. I'll extend the example.

Comment: I repeat, there is no column called "group" in the "Person" table, it's an association through a join table.

Comment: Ah, I see what the problem is. You're thinking in "tables" and "columns". When using ORM, you should be thinking in objects and properties. Ignore the join column, that's automatically taken care for you by Doctrine. You're Person Entity has a "groups" property and "getGroups" will automatically get those groups. DQL statments will also automatically  understand what to do with join tables.

Comment: Second paragraph: 
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#querying-for-objects-with-dql

Comment: I DO think in objects and properties, do believe me here, but it still doesn't follow Join table relationships automagically just because it says so in the $criteria parameter ( check \Doctrine\ORM\Persisters\BasicEntityPersister::getSelectSQL() )

Answer (score 0):

I would not use the associations to list group's members, but a custom repository call. This should be close enough:

```
class PersonRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function findPeopleInGroup(Group $group, $criteria, $limit, $offset){
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p');
        $qb->join('p.groups', 'g')
        ->where(':group MEMBER OF p.groups')
        ->setParameter('group', $group)
        ->orderBy('p.'.$criteria);

        $qb->setFirstResult($offset);
        $qb->setMaxResults($limit);

        return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think I understand more or less the DQL, but where is it set that you are looking for a "Person" entity?

Comment: When you're using a PersonRepository and create a query builder within it, it defaults to retrieve instances of the underlying entity. You can be specific and add `->select('p')` to it if you want.

Comment: Thanks, I imagined some "default magic" was involved but wanted to be sure. I'll run some tests on your solution. :)

Comment: \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager::createQueryBuilder() accepts no parameter, but if you change it to `$this->createQueryBuilder('p');` (\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager::createQueryBuilder($alias) ) it's ok :)

Comment: I'm trying thoroughly. It looks good. I will probably accept it (don't worry, I won't forget), but I'm making sure it does works, I would hate to "*unaccept*" it later :(